# Data dictionary and reporting tools

Tags: database, reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, data-dictionary

My question is about reporting tools and the concept of Data dictionary.
Is it necessary to use a Data dictionary in order to do good reports? and which tools use it? by tools i mean jasper reports, open reports, SQL Server Reporting services...
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very odd question as the data dictionary must be required for the obvious reason that it tells the reporting api what format the data will be in and how joins etc. may be done. Hence in order to display data from the database or to act on any tables within the database you have to have a data dictionary. Interestingly XML cheats as it uses the concept of a #PCDATA base type which is used in lieu of typing information where it does not exist.

I hope that answers your question, I'm sure that I can expand if you require.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually I'm beginner in reporting and i wanted to understand how a reporting tool works. Do you have any useful documentation concerning this topic.

Comment: im sorry the only documentation i have is experience and my memory, i'm sure others can point you towards literature that i fear i cannot

Answer (score 0):

different tools are working differently. some access directly the data(base) others (e.g. like List & Label) sit "in between", allowing a more flexible approach. See here for a small schema about this: [Functional Principle of Reporting](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/functional-principle-reporting-with-List-Label)

This allows the tool in this example to work with nearly any programming environment. That said for .NET there are components available to simplify things:
[Simplification in reporting with a .NET component](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/.NET-Visual-Studio-WPF)

Hope that helps to clarify things...

Comment: If i understood well what you wrote the dictionary is a recommended practice but things could work out good without it. What's the other approaches? As @MD-Tech said:"it tells the reporting api what format the data will be in and how joins etc. may be done. Hence in order to display data from the database or to act on any tables within the database you have to have a data dictionary" how could that be done without a data dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a report without using a DD. But DD can give you a whole lot of extra flavor to it. Generally speaking, DD helps you maintain all the data you have. Once you document your system, it's easy to find a needle in the haystack. Furthermore, it helps others to find the information they need. There is no mandatory in using DD, but they can help, a lot. Are you using the SQL Server? Or was it just an example?